# How to give system date while creating SQL table?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server creating table error.

How to give system date, system date + 2 days while creating a table?

Is the system date the same as the current date?

Comment: What is the error? What do you mean by system date? What code are you using? Your question is really unclear as it stands.

Comment: where is your error... please add create table code and your error.

Comment: use  **dateadd** function `DateAdd(dd, 2, getdate()))`

Comment: Your question implies that you think it may not be if not please tell us what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [SQL DEFAULT Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) as shown below *if I understood your question properly*:

```
Create table Test(id int
  , name varchar(20)
  , dtDate datetime default DateAdd(dd, 2, getdate()))

insert into Test (id, name) values
(1, 'A')

select * from Test
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e5f546cce4e77f7dad03da0619734e9) demo.

Comment: it's good answer for this Question. i test it ....work well